# In glmnet what does number of data passes mean and how is it computed?

Tags: r, glmnet

The [glmnet reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/glmnet.pdf) states that the S3 glmnet object (return value of the glmnet() function) contains the variable `npasses` which is defined as:

> total passes over the data summed over all lambda values

For example:

```
$ R
> library(glmnet)
> X <- matrix(rnorm(100 * 20), 100, 20)
> y <- rnorm(100)
> model <- glmnet(X,y)
> model$npasses
[1] 288
```

I would like to know what the number 288 means and how it's computed. **For example, given the above does 288 mean that each element of the X matrix was accessed exactly 288 times? Is it computed by incrementing a counter for each element of the X matrix when accessed? If so what if some elements of the matrix get accessed more often than others? etc.**

I've looked at the source code and it seems to me that the `nlp` variable is more like an iteration counter as opposed to what I understand under data pass. However, the FORTRAN code is pretty impenetrable so I might be wrong. I'm hoping that someone who is familiar with the code can answer this question.